# Will we do melacha in the seventh millennium?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, behar

BH

[In Toras Kohanim to the beginning of parshas Behar](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%9B%D7%94), on the verse saying that one should cause the land to "rest" like Shabbos, there are several sections where it says that we might think that many types of melachos which are prohibited on shabbos might also be prohibited on the shveees, but then for each case it brings some verse to prove otherwise

For example

" "ושבתה הארץ"-- יכול מלחפור בורות שיחין ומערות ומלתקן את המקואות? תלמוד לומר "שדך לא תזרע וכרמך לא תזמר".  אין לי אלא לזרע ולזמור"

Then later it specifies the type of work that's prohibited, even though it's also compared to regular Shabbos

"שבת לה' "-- כשם שנאמר בשבת בראשית "שבת לה' " כך נאמר בשביעית "שבת לה' ".

"שדך לא תזרע וכרמך לא תזמר"-- כל מלאכה שבשדך וכל מלאכה שבכרמך.

Seemingly implying that there is a strong relationship between the Sabbatical year and Shabbos itself, that one would think that at least many melachos which are prohibited on Shabbos might also be prohibited on it, if not for some specific proofs indicating otherwise

Now the question is in regards to the seventh millennium, which is also referred to as "Shabbos", as we say in Psalm 92:

https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%22%D7%92_%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A6%D7%91_%D7%90

"מִזְמוֹר שִׁיר לְיוֹם הַשַּׁבָּת:"
And Rashi there says:

""מזמור שיר" - של לוים (נביאים)

"ליום השבת" - שאומרים אותו בשבתות והוא מדבר בענין העולם הבא שכולו שבת"

That the world to come, which will be the world of the resurrection of the dead in the seventh millennium, with souls in bodies, in this physical world (see mibartenura beginning of chapter Chelek), then maybe the same comparison may apply to that and the actual Shabbos, similar to how it applies between Shabbos and the Shviis, if not for the specific verses in that context indicating otherwise?

A comparison is indeed brought in chapter [Chelek](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%99%D7%90), but it doesn't specifically say if melacha will be prohibited or not:

"כשם שהשביעית משמטת שנה אחת לז' שנים כך העולם משמט אלף שנים לשבעת אלפים שנה שנאמר ונשגב ה' לבדו ביום ההוא ואומר (תהלים צב, א) מזמור שיר ליום השבת יום שכולו שבת ואומר (תהלים צ, ד) כי אלף שנים בעיניך כיום אתמול כי יעבור תנא דבי אליהו ששת אלפים שנה הוי עלמא שני אלפים תוהו שני אלפים תורה שני אלפים ימות המשיח"

Comment: There's a lot about this. Ramchal says 7th millennium the world will be mabul and we will be in Olam Haneshamot until the resurrection in 8th millennium. We pray on shabbat benching for a day that is "all shabbat", Olam haba eternal rest from any fixing or innovative, just enjoying the reward. 7th lubavitch Rebbe said his generation is shabbos, no more self improvement, focus is now on welcoming Hashem into the world. If any of these interest you I can try to write up to answer with sources

Comment: That would be interesting. The question is mainly asking according to those who say that it will be physical bodies, after the resurrection. Will the bodies still be allowed to do melacha? Also I've heard the Rebbe say that we're after chatzos of erev Shabbos since 5751 but I haven't heard him say we're in shabbos itself

Comment: All of the points I made are based on opinions that hold by physical bodies. The question is probably not valid. It's not that we won't be allowed to do melacha, but we won't be able to. I think it's a really good question and if I feel confident enough to answer I'll do so. Hatzlacha and thanks

Comment: @RabbiKaii ok . Is the world of souls a world containing physical bodies?

Comment: Sorry, I am not learned in other sources about what happens from the year 6000-7000, but according to Maamar HaIkkarim Ch. 8, most people will be in Olam HaNeshamot and the tzaddikim will "grow wings and hover over the water for 1000 years" and then there will be a new world that is Olam Haba in the year 7000 that I believe the harachaman is referring to. A new resurrection will take place.

Comment: @rabbi hi again. Ok I hear you. The question though is focusing on the view of the ramban and others who hold that the ultimate world is this physical world, not the world of souls

Comment: To be clear, I am talking about exactly that opinion, check the source